# Javascript - change a json object array values into multiple strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am receiving an json object from an API. What I do after (just for information: some string analysis of each key value), works great for 90% of these objects I receive as the key value is a string as show below.

```
{ ID: '0012784',
utm_source: 'wesbite',
utm_medium: 'redirection',
utm_campaign: 'media'}
```

But for 10% of them, some of the keys might be arrays, like below:

```
problematicJson =
{ ID: '0012784',
utm_source: 'website',
utm_medium: [ 'redirection', 'somethingelse' ],
utm_campaign: [ 'nicestuff', 'again' ] }
```

I would need to change the object above into this new object so that my script analysis, which requires pure strings, work.

Using javascript, how  to "break" and recreate the object problematicJson into what's below

```
allStringsJson =
{ ID: '0012784',
utm_source: 'website',
utm_medium: 'redirection',
utm_medium = 'somethignelse',
utm_campaign: 'nicestuff',
utm_campaign = 'again' }
```

I also need to deal with a special case: when the values isndie the array are the same like below:

```
problematicJsonWithSimilarValues = 
{ ID: '0012784',
utm_source: 'website',
utm_medium: [ 'redirection', 'redirection' ],
utm_campaign: [ 'lorem', 'lorem' ] }
```

So I need to write somethign where I don't get multiple lines where the key AND the vlaue are the same, like

```
allStringsJson =
{ ID: '0012784',
utm_source: 'wesbite',
utm_medium: 'redirection',
utm_medium = 'redirection',
utm_campaign: 'lorem',
utm_campaign = 'lorem' }
```

But I need to remove those similar lines from the new clean json object which would be for problematicJsonWithSimilarValues:

```
cleanObject =
{ ID: '0012784',
utm_source: 'website',
utm_medium: 'redirection',
utm_campaign = 'lorem' }
```

I tried a bunch of methods like reduce, split...to no success.

How to achieve this ?

Comment: You can't have duplicated key in JSON even if the values are different.

Comment: ho I did not know that

Comment: I see, then my question is out:) I'll have to change my script so that when the vlaue is a string it does X and when the value is an array it split it into 2 strings...

Comment: You cannot have assignments like `utm_medium = 'somethignelse',` in Javascript objects. Also note that **none** of the code snippets you present are JSON.

Comment: @connexo what do you mean? what are they then? what type of objects?

Comment: They look like Javascript objects. JSON is always a `String`. There is no such thing as a *JSON object*. If it's an object, it's Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This wouldn't work.

In JSON and in a Javascript Object each key ist unique. So you could not have more than one property named `utm_medium`.

But you could use [`Array.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join), to create a single string concatinated with all of the elements in the array. Do something like:

```
utm_medium: Array.isArray(utm_medium) ? utm_medium.split(' ') : utm_medium
```